# How to write code for pyramid output in RUBY Language

Tags: ruby

I'm a new web developer and need assistance generating a given output to a problem:

```
def fib(n)
    if (n<=2)
        return 1
    else
        return (fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))
    end
end

puts "Enter the number of terms:-"
n=gets.chomp.to_i

puts "The first #{n} terms of fibonnaci series are:-"
for c in 1..n
    puts fib(c)
end
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the number of terms:-
5
The first 5 terms of fibonnaci series are:-
1
1
2
3
5
```

Excepted output:

```
1
22
333
55555
88888888
```

How would I be able to make my code produce the target output?

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected output? The mapping from fibonacci terms to expected output seems to be `1 → 1`, `1 → 22`, `2 → 333`, `3 → 55555` and `5 → 88888888`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate through the range and calculate fibonacci for every member and you can multuply string with `*`

```
def fibonacci(n)
  return n if (0..1).include?(n)
  fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
end

def print_pyramide(n)
  (2..(n + 1)).each do |i|
    fib = fibonacci(i)
    puts fib.to_s * fib
  end
end
```

```
print_pyramide(2)
# will print
# 1
# 22
```

```
print_pyramide(5)
# will print
# 1
# 22
# 333
# 55555
# 88888888
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerator::produce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce), which made it's debut in Ruby v2.7.

```
Enumerator.produce([1, 1]) { |n1, n2| [n2, n1 + n2] }
          .with_index(1)
          .take(5)
          .each { |(_,f),i| puts f.to_s * i }
```

prints

```
1
22
333
5555
88888
```

---

Note:

```
enum = Enumerator.produce([1, 1]) { |n1, n2| [n2, n1 + n2] }
  #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Producer:0x00007fb18084de18>:each>
```

```
enum.next #=> [1, 1]
enum.next #=> [1, 2]
enum.next #=> [2, 3]
enum.next #=> [3, 5]
enum.next #=> [5, 8]
```